# Running program from pendrive before windows boots

Tags: windows

How do I auto-run a program from Pen drive before Windows logs in, starts or even before it boots up?

I want to open command prompt before login. To do this, I tried changing the command prompt name to sethc.exe (sticky keys) which might run before I login into my account and it actually worked, but to do this I must have password and administrator privileges, so without that how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is the program an executable file?

Did you try looking into Windows registry? The following key is where the virus/malware usually attached itself during windows logon. A warning though, any mistake will cause you unable to go into Windows, you have to remotely modify the registry using Bootdisk.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Comment: yes the program is executable file.No i didn't look into windows registry